# AJAX POST 500 Internal Server Error on hosting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm develop something that need some data to load on AJAX (using POST method).

When I'm build the code on localhost (using XAMPP on Windows 7). It works pretty well.

But, when I'm moved the code to hosting server, It give me a 500 Internal Server Error..

Here's the code that send the AJAX Request

```
$.post("the-link-to-ajax-handler",
{ 
    //some parameter
    roomid : roomid,
    amenities : amenities,
},
function(data){
    //process that I do when ajax complete
}
```

And here's the AJAX Handler (using PHP)

```
$roomid      = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['roomid']);
$amenities      = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['amenities']);
echo $roomid."<br/>".$amenities;die();
```

*I'm trying to print the parameter but no luck, I'm still get the 500 Error

Screenshot of Network Panel from process on hosting
[image]

And here's the Screenshot Network Panel from process on localhost (definitely with the same code)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Are you missing any javascript plugin files or the plugin files path is not defined you faced the 500 internal server error.

2) Hosting server is Case Sensitive check the Variable values.

3) If you move to ajax before alerting the flow.

Comment: thank you very much. You make me realize I forgot to delete some unnecessary  `include` on the PHP. LOL

Comment: fu*k! why php servers are Case Sensitive for default setting !!! waste my lots of time for debugging

Answer (score 2):

Read your error logs to find out problem or try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to your code then run again.

Comment: First of all, you should create a file test.php as below.
    
    <?php
        echo 'OK';

Then access http://yourdomain.com/test.php  to confirm your hosting working properly.

Comment: It say's my page is not working tho... So what I need to do to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "the-link-to-ajax-handle", // Url to which the request is send
    type: "POST", // Type of request to be send, called as method
    data: {roomid:roomid,amenities:amenities}, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and values
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function (data) {
    console.log('failed');
});
```

Comment: still giving the same error.. 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: have any redirect code in your 'roomdetails.php' of any without condition?

Comment: please open `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on `roomdetails.php`  and show this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, i noticed that my php files permission was set to `0755`. i changed it to `0644` and it worked well.